# LINQ expression duplicates values on select instead of cycling them

Tags: c#, linq, class, datagrid, anonymous-types

I have a class to store some info about the files contained in folder:

```
static class fileList
{
    public static IEnumerable<files> fL;
}

public class files
{
    private static string _name = "";
    private static long _size;
    private static DateTime _creationDate;

    public string name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }

    public long size
    {
        get { return _size; }
        set { _size = value; }
    }

    public DateTime creationDate
    {
        get { return _creationDate; }
        set { _creationDate = value; }
    }
}
```

the files list is then populated via:

```
fileList.fL = Directory.EnumerateFiles(folder, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            .Select(x => new 
            {
                name = x.ToString(),
                size = new FileInfo(x).Length,
                creationDate = new FileInfo(x).CreationTime
            });
```

Now the returned structure will be an IEnumerable of the (example) 3 files in the folder.

Up until this point everything is working. The problem raises when i try to return a declared type and not an anonymous one

```
var fL = Directory.EnumerateFiles(folder, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        fileList.fL = fL.Select(x => new files()
            {
                name = x.ToString(),
                size = new FileInfo(x).Length,
                creationDate = new FileInfo(x).CreationTime
            });
```

This will return 3 `IEnumerable` items but all of them containing the exact same info. Which as far I can see is the last file entry returned by the `EnumerateFiles` method.

The reason why I would like to return a type is because these info then will go into a DataGridView and if the data source is an anonymous type it will be not possible to perform any changes since the type is ReadOnly.

Comment: Did you try by removing the static modifier from backing fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have static variables in your `files` class.

```
private static string _name = "";
private static long _size;
private static DateTime _creationDate;
```

Static class members are shared for all instances of the class, so when you are setting `name="fielname"` all instances will return `"filename"` for the `name` property. Why you need this static fields?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to not fully unserstand what the `static`-modifier is about. In short it is used when a member belongs to *all* instances of a class, whereas non-static means that every instance of your class (whenever you write `new files()`) has its own values for the member. In your case the static results in all instances of your class having the same values, those from the last iteration of your `fileList.Fl`-collection. You may also have a further look on the [MSDN for `static`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/98f28cdx.aspx).

Having said this your problem is resolved by removing the `static`-modifier from your backing-fields as others alrready mentioned.

Apart from this you should read about [naming-conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043(v=vs.100).aspx#Anchor_1), e.g. class-names being written in CamelCase - for example class `Files` instead of `files` or even better - as actually every instance of your class represents *one single* file, just use `File`. Similary rename `fileList` to `FileList` and all your public members to CamelCase as well.